# Which sentence is phrased correctly

Tags: grammar, sentence

> I think you set the bar of expectations too high for this product.
>
> I think you set the bar of expectations for this product too high.

Do both work, or is one of those worded wrong?

Comment: Ditch "of expectations".  "Set the bar too high" is a well-known idiom, and adding "of expectations" only confuses the reader.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends on what exactly what you mean. The first one,

> I think you set the bar of expectations too high for this product

means that this product's bar (of expectations) is too high, but the same bar set for a different product might not be too high.  The second one,

> I think you set the bar of expectations for this product too high

means that the bar set for this product is too high, but if you lower the bar, it will be all right.  In other words, the first one should be used if you want to change the product, the second one if you want to change the bar.